# Limiting google prediction to a specific country doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm doing the following:

```
    FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder requestBuilder = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder();
    if (limitToCountry != null) {
        requestBuilder.setCountry(limitToCountry.toLowerCase());
    }
    requestBuilder.setSessionToken(HPlaces.getAutocompleteSessionToken());
    requestBuilder.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS);

    try {
        mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.item_select_address,
                latLngBounds.build(),
                requestBuilder
        );
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //Issue with latLngBounds.build() not having included points in it
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

The problem is that if for instance the limiting country is "ro" (Romania), and if i query google, it also returns results from other countries. Why is that ?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                        .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
                        .setCountry("US")
                        .build();
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                        .setFilter(autocompleteFilter)
                        .build(this);
```

Comment: AutocompleteFilter <--- cannot resolve symbol. The class has been deprecated. Already tried this